# How can interfaces implement progressively more-strict typed properties?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, interface

I'm working on a series of data structures. Some require a specific number of dimensions (like quad-trees or oct-trees) and some allow for any number (such as kd-trees). I'd like to implement my different structures and interfaces as follows:

```
public struct Point : IPoint // An n-dimensional point
public struct Point2D : IPoint // A 2-dimensional point

public interface IPointEntity
{
    IPoint Location { get; }
}
public interface IPointEntity2D : IPointEntity
{
    Point2D Location { get; }
}
```

This way, I can create classes like this:

```
public class Quadtree
{
    public void Add(IPointEntity2D value) {...}
}

public class KdTree
{
    public void Add(IPointEntity value) {...}
}
```

However, I'm told  that `IPointEntity2D` must declare `Location` as `New` since it hides `IPointEntity.Location`. This defeats the purpose, though, as I would have to implement them both separately. It seems to me that the 2D implementation should fulfill the n-D interface's requirement. How can I accomplish this?

---

**EDIT:**
I've now got it implemented as per Jon Skeet's suggestion:

```
public struct Point : IPoint // An n-dimensional point
public struct Point2D : IPoint // A 2-dimensional point

public interface IPointEntity<T> where T : IPoint
{
    T Location { get; }
}

public class Quadtree<T> where T : IPointEntity<Point2D>
{
    public void Add(T value) {...}
}

public class KdTree<T> where T : IPointEntity<IPoint>
{
    public void Add(T value) {...}
}
```

But when I try to make an entity, I can't use them in both appropriate classes, like I had hoped:

```
public class Sprite2D : IPointEntity<Point2D>
{
    public Point2D Location { get; set; }
}
public class Sprite3D : IPointEntity<Point3D>
{
    public Point3D Location { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var quadtree = new Quadtree<Sprite2D>(); // Works just great
    var kdTree2D = new KdTree<Sprite2D>();   // Doesn't work
    var kdTree3D = new KdTree<Sprite3D>();   // Doesn't work
}
```

Comment: You haven't shownhow `Sprite2D` and `Sprite3D` are declared.

Comment: @Jon - Sorry about that. There's really not much too them tho. Is there a way to make them work in all applicable structures?

Comment: You could declare KdTree with *two* type parameters: `class KdTree<TEntity, TPoint> where TEntity : IPointEntity<TPoint> where TPoint : IPoint`

Comment: This works great. I wish .Net could be a little smarter about it, but this works fine as a workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for covariant return types - they just don't exist in .NET. You have to implement the two properties separately, using explicit interface implementation to avoid them clashing.

One potential workaround is to use a generic interface instead:

```
public interface IPointEntity<T> where T : IPoint
{
    T Location { get; }
}
```

Note that this would *also* allow a class to implement `IPointEntity<Point>` and avoid boxing a `Point` into an `IPoint` when it's accessed.

Comment: This solves some of my problem. More importantly, though (and perhaps not well enough stated in my question) I want the same class to be usable in both a specific dimension, and a non-specific dimension. I'll edit my post above.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a generic interface

```
public interface IPointEntity<T> where T : IPoint 
{
    T Location { get; }
}
```

and let `IPointEntity2D` inherit `IPointEntity<Point2D>`.

Comment: Nope, it's NoCanDo for two interfaces each with a `Location` property, but I was writing up mostly the same idea as you at the same time :) I don't think there's any need for IPointEntity2D at that point though... just use `IPointEntity<Point2D>` instead.